# Cdsを用いたArduinoIDEのプログラムで0~1023段階の入力をanalogWrite(LED,val/10);とする理由を教えてください

Tags: c++, arduino

初めての質問でよく分かりませんがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 何かの書籍やWeb上の記事を参考にしているのなら、それが何で何処にあるか等を追記してください。例えばこんな記事が質問と類似の内容を扱っていそうです。[第5回 光センサーでArduino（アルディーノ）への入力を試してみる！](https://deviceplus.jp/arduino/entry_005/), [Arduinoにセンサーを接続しよう](https://techfactory.itmedia.co.jp/tf/articles/1907/18/news019.html), [光センサ（CDSセル）で遊ぼう](http://jkoba.net/prototyping/arduino/cds_practice.html) これらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問をブラッシュアップしてみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Answer (score 2):

「なぜ」はそういう仕様を策定した人に訊かないとわからないでしょう。まあ妄想するに `CdS` センサーに明るい光を当てる＝LEDがより強く光る、という動作はそれを操作する人間にとって直観的にわかりやすいから、なんぢゃないですかね？ LED の明るさを 1024 等分しても人間の目では判別できないとか人間工学的配慮も若干あるかもしれないですね。

# 硫化カドミウムだから `CdS` は正しくて `Cds` はおかしい・・・